# iteratively intersecting line segments in Sympy... is there a better way?

Tags: python, geometry, networkx, sympy

OK. I have the points that comprise the borders of a polygon. I want to (a) use Sympy's geometry module to determine, from all of the possible line-segments between any pair of points, which segments do not cross the perimeter. This result will be the "edges" that are allowed to be used in (b) a shortest_distance analysis in Networkx. My end goal is to iterate this process through many shapes, but I've hard-coded the coordinates for just 1 shape in this example.

```
import numpy
import networkx as nx
from sympy import geometry
from itertools import combinations
from matplotlib import pyplot as plot
arr_bou = numpy.array([[-542.62545014,  961.34455209],
   [-544.45425379,  961.34455209],
   [-544.45425379,  962.25895392],
   [-547.19745928,  962.25895392],
   [-547.19745928,  963.17335575],
   [-549.02626294,  963.17335575],
   [-549.02626294,  964.08775758],
   [-550.85506659,  964.08775758],
   [-550.85506659,  961.34455209],
   [-552.68387025,  961.34455209],
   [-552.68387025,  962.25895392],
   [-553.59827208,  962.25895392],
   [-553.59827208,  965.91656123],
   [-552.68387025,  965.91656123],
   [-552.68387025,  967.7453649 ],
   [-551.76946842,  967.7453649 ],
   [-551.76946842,  968.65976672],
   [-550.85506659,  968.65976672],
   [-550.85506659,  967.7453649 ],
   [-548.11186111,  967.7453649 ],
   [-548.11186111,  965.91656123],
   [-547.19745928,  965.91656123],
   [-547.19745928,  964.08775758],
   [-546.28305745,  964.08775758],
   [-546.28305745,  965.00215941],
   [-543.53985197,  965.00215941],
   [-543.53985197,  963.17335575],
   [-542.62545014,  963.17335575],
   [-542.62545014,  964.08775758],
   [-540.79664648,  964.08775758],
   [-540.79664648,  963.17335575],
   [-539.88224465,  963.17335575],
   [-539.88224465,  962.25895392],
   [-542.62545014,  962.25895392],
   [-542.62545014,  961.34455209]])

boundXY = []
for i in arr_bou:
    boundXY.append((i[0],i[1]))

points     = [geometry.Point(i) for i in boundXY]
poly       = geometry.Polygon(*points) # use the * first to unpack the points (necessary to avoid errors)


G          = nx.Graph()
positions  = {}                                  # build a dictionary
for i in xrange(len(boundXY)):                   # that contains coordinates
    positions[i] = boundXY[i]                    # of each node on the graph's perimeter
G.add_path(positions.keys())# add nodes to graph w/ boundary edges
G.add_path([min(G.nodes()),max(G.nodes())])    combos_o   = list(combinations(positions.keys(),2))
combos     = [i for i in combos_o if i not in G.edges()]

keepcombos = []
for combo in combos:
    pt1 = positions[combo[0]]
    pt2 = positions[combo[1]]
    line = geometry.Polygon(pt1,pt2)
    # there are 4 polygon sides that do not count as intersections
    # because 2 sides will intersect a point on each end
    test = True
    for side in poly.sides:
        if side.p1 != geometry.Point(pt1) and side.p1 != geometry.Point(pt2):
            if side.p2 != geometry.Point(pt1) and side.p2 != geometry.Point(pt2):
                if geometry.intersection(line,side):
                    test = False
                    break
                else:
                    try:
                        if poly.encloses(line.midpoint):
                            pass
                        else:
                            test = False
                            break
                    except NotImplementedError:
                        pass
    if test == True:
        keepcombos.append(combo)
G.add_edges_from(keepcombos)
```

I've gotten this to work for small polygons (14 vertices) but this takes FOREVER with even just a 35 vertices, and other polygons will be larger than this still.

Is there a more efficient way of finding all within-polygon node-pairs?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that sped the process up by about 13x (for a polygon with 35 points (like the data listed above), the old method from the code in the question took about 4hours to find all line segments inside the polygon. This new method took 18 minutes instead.)

Above I was iteratated through the points, and at each iteration looked at each border ("side") individually to see if the lines intersected. I changed this to instead intersect the line with the entire polygon. If it lines inside or on the edge, there should only be 2 points where it intersects, so if the length of the intersection is >2, I throw the combination out

```
for combo in combos:
    pt1  = geometry.Point(positions[combo[0]],evaluate=False)
    pt2  = geometry.Point(positions[combo[1]],evaluate=False)
    line = geometry.Polygon(pt1,pt2)
    try:
        if poly.encloses(line.midpoint):
            pass
        else:
            continue
    except NotImplementedError:
        continue
    intersect = geometry.intersection(line,poly)
    if len(intersect)>2:
        continue
    keepcombos.append(combo)
```

This list "keepcombos" now has all of the lines (or networkx "edges") that I wish to include in a Dijkstra path analysis

Answer (score 0):

If the convex hull is the set of points defining a convex polygon containing all others

```
>>> coords = [[-542.62545014,  961.34455209],
...    [-544.45425379,  961.34455209],
...    [-544.45425379,  962.25895392],
...    [-547.19745928,  962.25895392],

...    [-542.62545014,  962.25895392],
...    [-542.62545014,  961.34455209]]
>>> from sympy import *
>>> pts = [Point(*i) for i in coords]
>>> h = convex_hull(*pts)
```

then are you just interested in all points that are not on the perimeter? Once you know those points then do you just want to generate all pair-wise combinations of those points?

```
inside = [p for p in pts if p not in h.vertices]
from sympy.utilities.iterables import combinations
pairs = combinations(inside, 2)
```

Looking at https://www.desmos.com/calculator/up4k2qkxy9 I see that a few points appear to fall on an edge so perhaps they shouldn't be included as "inside" points. But hopefully you get the gist of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the points inside the convex hull are not what I am interested in. The points in "coords" are the perimeter of the polygon, so there are no points inside. What I am interested in doing is finding all the line segments that connect 2 points that are entirely inside the polygon. I think I found a more efficient solution, I will post my new code now as the answer. Thank you so much again!